# VPN network to home address

Tags: networking, vpn, network-location

I am looking for some help with setting up a VPN.

Long story short, I moved to San Diego however my employer is requiring me to stay in Sacramento even though I work remotely 100% of the time.

The PC that the company provided is pretty locked down and essentially connects to a virtual desktop. I cannot install any VPN software on the PC. It's impossible to do anything other than log in and work.

So I purchased two TPLINK ER605 VPN routers. One is installed at my home address in Sacramento and the other in my new apartment in San Diego.

I need to configure the VPN router in San Diego to route all traffic to Sacramento.
That way it appears that I am working out of Sacramento.

What is the configuration needed to make this happen?

Thanks,

Comment: Welcome to Superuser. Many of us (especially those who can answer this kind of question) are IT professionals and will not assist people in hacking/exceeding their authority- even if we may sympathise with the poster.  We also expect people to advise what they have tried and where they are stuck.  You might want to consider deleting this question, attempting what you need to do and come back with a focussed technical question without ethical baggage.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because answeing it could be unethical.

Comment: Can an employer demand you live in a given city to telecommute? I'd challenge that requirement. [I'm UK & I'm pretty certain you couldn't demand that here]. Ask a lawyer.

Comment: Hey @Tetsujin .. I am in the US and no lawyer .. but I don't think you can do that here either.  That still doesn't help him fix the problem but I have to agree with davidgo.  He needs to make his company solve this.